# How to make Incoming Links appear as a drop-down in Sharepoint wiki?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, moss

The incoming links feature of the Sharepoint wiki is cool, but it's a hassle having to go to another page to see the list.

Is it possible to replace the Incoming Links hyperlink with a drop-down menu showing the links on the same page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by the code found [here](http://mo.notono.us/2009/01/moss-add-incoming-links-to-wiki-page.html), [here](http://blog.vegaitsourcing.rs/2008/09/adding-new-wiki-page-link.html) and [here](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/?p=1341), I created this file in 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\WikiMiniConsole.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"   AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SPHttpUtility" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBarButton" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBarButton.ascx" %>

<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="WikiMiniConsole" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">
        <div class="ms-wikieditouter">
        <table  id="miniconsole" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
            <table class="ms-wikieditsecond" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
                <table class="ms-wikieditthird" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
                    <!-- this is for the orange cast inside the menu -->
                    <table class="ms-wikieditorange" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ms-wikieditorangeinnera" style=";width:100%;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-wikitoolbar" runat="server">
                        <Template_Buttons>
                            <SharePoint:WikiEditItemButton Text= "<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_wikieditpage%>" runat="server"/>
                            <SharePoint:WikiPageHistoryButton Text= "<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_viewpagehistory%>" ButtonID="WikiPageHistory" runat="server"/>
                            <SharePoint:WikiIncomingLinksButton Text= "Incoming Links" ButtonID="WikiIncomingLinks" runat="server"/>
                        </Template_Buttons>
                        </wssuc:ToolBar>
                    </td></tr></table>
                 </td></tr></table>
            </td></tr></table>
        </td></tr></table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() { 

    var toc = "<div id='toc' style='background:#EBF3FF;"
                +"border:1px solid #6F9DD9;display:none;"
                +"position:absolute;top:127;right:11;width:250px;"
                +"text-align:left;'></div>";

    $("td.ms-bodyareaframe:first").append(toc);

    //get the url for the incoming links page 
    u = $("a[id$=WikiIncomingLinks_LinkText]")[0].href; 

    //get the target container and load it with the incoming links 
    //filtered to show the links list only 
    $("#toc").load(u + " .ms-propertysheet");

    $("#toc").wrapInner("<ul style='padding:2px;margin:0;list-style-type:none;'></ul>");
    $("#toc a").wrap("<li style='padding:0;margin:0;'></li>");
    $("#toc li").prepend("<img style='margin-right:5px;' alt='' src='/_layouts/images/square.gif'/>");
    $("#incominglinks").click(function(){
        $("#toc").toggle();
    });

    // override the target of our hyperlink to bring up the menu
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMiniConsole_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_RptControls_WikiIncomingLinks_LinkText").attr("href", "#")
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMiniConsole_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_RptControls_WikiIncomingLinks_LinkText").click(function(){
        $("#toc").toggle();
    });  
}); 
</script> 



        </div></div>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

After resetting IIS, the change is applied to all wiki pages on your site.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

This looks great however when I created the file and restarted IIS the drop down for incoming links did not appear. Is there anything else I must do to get this to work I'm on MOSS07?

Cheers

Comment: @Rowan, I suggest you start by getting the code in the three links I posted working first. My code is essentially a combination of all three. Those links have better step-by-step instructions than in my post.